# Influence a linear percentage calculation to rise quicker at the beginning?

Tags: php, math, curve

I'm doing a really basic progress percentage calculation, at the moment it's a linear calculation so:

```
0 -> 0%
max/10 -> 10%
max -> 100%
```

The calculation is simply like this:

```
$max = 4000;
$current = 1450;
$percent = ceil($current/$max*100);
```

Easy as.

but I need it to make it look as if the progress bar increases quicker at the beginning, basically boosting the initial visual progress.

I really should know that but my brain isn't retrieving way old maths (I blame too much coffee).

I guess it's a kind of easing I'm after; how can I change this - very simple - formula to have a different affect on the progression curve?

*Note: That's php obviously, but that should be the same in any language.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a quadratic adjustment with a small parameter (`$sf`).
This is the same as yours for `$sf=0`. However you can tweak $sf to get the behavior you want.

```
$sf=0.2;
$p = $current/$max;
$percent = ceil($p + $sf * ($p *(1-$p) )) * 100);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that ceil($current/$max). That seems to massively influence the result, works well without though..

Comment: Yeah, definitely works without the ceil bit.. can you edit your answer?

Comment: Ah you're right. Sorry that was copy paste error from yoru code :(. You'll need the `ceil` around the $percent code if you want whole numbers - fixed now.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that $sf should be confined between 0 and 1 to keep the resulting range within a 0 to 100%?

Comment: Valid ranges for sf are [0,1] with >0 giving an increase in initial speed. YOu can also use sf<0, but it give the wrong behavior for your case, speeding up as we approach the end, rather than slowing down.

Answer (score 0):

One such curve is sine.

```
<?php

$k = 3.1415/2;

$max = 100;

print sin(0 / $max * $k) . "\n";
print sin(50 / $max * $k) . "\n";
print sin(100 / $max * $k) . "\n";

?>
```

That prints:

```
0
0.70709040200144
0.99999999892691
```

Comment: That doesn't allow for much flexibility. I'd like to tweak the affect on the curve